# Android CTS doesn't run

Tags: android, cts

I am getting below error when in try to run CTS on Android P. Any idea what is going wrong?

$ ./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed

cts-tf > run cts

Error:

```
02-19 15:21:36 E/TestInvoca`enter code here`tion: Caught AssertionError while running invocation: java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731))>`enter code here`
02-19 15:21:36 E/TestInvocation: expected null, but was:<Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731))>
java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731))>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:755)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:737)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:747)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.InstrumentationTest.run(InstrumentationTest.java:707)
    at com.android.tradefed.testtype.AndroidJUnitTest.run(AndroidJUnitTest.java:264)
    at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.ApkInstrumentationPreparer.instrument(ApkInstrumentationPreparer.java:129)
    at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.ApkInstrumentationPreparer.run(ApkInstrumentationPreparer.java:77)
    at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.PreconditionPreparer.setUp(PreconditionPreparer.java:65)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.InvocationExecution.doSetup(InvocationExecution.java:196)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.prepareAndRun(TestInvocation.java:356)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.performInvocation(TestInvocation.java:205)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.invoke(TestInvocation.java:667)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler$InvocationThread.run(CommandScheduler.java:566)

02-19 15:21:36 W/ResultReporter: Invocation failed: java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731))>
02-19 15:21:36 D/ResultReporter: Saved logs for device_logcat_test in /home/sam/Downloads/android-cts-9.0_r10-linux_x86-arm/android-cts/tools/../../android-cts/logs/2020.02.19_15.21.35/inv_1420379781159145465/device_logcat_test_8965375754550142253.txt.gz
02-19 15:21:36 D/ResultReporter: Saved logs for device_logcat_teardown in /home/sam/Downloads/android-cts-9.0_r10-linux_x86-arm/android-cts/tools/../../android-cts/logs/2020.02.19_15.21.35/inv_1420379781159145465/device_logcat_teardown_8630617971443262202.txt.gz
02-19 15:21:36 D/ResultReporter: Saved logs for host_log in /home/sam/Downloads/android-cts-9.0_r10-linux_x86-arm/android-cts/tools/../../android-cts/logs/2020.02.19_15.21.35/inv_1420379781159145465/host_log_1244842110714179011.txt.gz
```

02-19 15:21:36 I/SuiteResultReporter: 
    ============================================
    ================= Results ==================
    =============== Consumed Time ==============
    Total aggregated tests run time: 0 ms
    =============== Summary ===============
    Total Run time: 1s
    0/0 modules completed
    Total Tests       : 0
    PASSED            : 0
    FAILED            : 0 
    ============== End of Results ==============
    ============================================

Answer (score 0):

From the error stack seems like the issue is with adb version being used within the host machine.

Suspecting that instrumentation command is not able to run successfully due to failure within the binder.

Can you please update the adb version to 1.0.40 and above and retry running CTS.